# .htaccess ErrorDocument 404 to use RewriteBase value

Tags: .htaccess

I've set my RewriteBase to /folder/. Is there a way to declare ErrorDocument 404 to /404.php without doing it like this: ErrorDocument 404 /folder/404.php ?

My aim is to only declare my base once in my htaccess file.

My .htaccess look like below:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /folder/
ErrorDocument 404 /folder/index.php
```

Comment: There is no way to do this. RewriteBase and ErrorDocument are two diffrent directives you cant combine them.

Comment: ErrorDocument has nothing whatsoever to do with the rewrite engine, so it has no reason to care for directives specific to that module either. _“My aim is to only declare my base once in my htaccess file”_ - there simply _is_ no “base” for ErrorDocument.

Comment: Thanks! Why does htaccess have to be so different from everything else!